# How do I get a map file within arm-none-eabi-gcc

Tags: gcc

Deal All,
I'm trying to get a map file with arm-none-eabi-gcc.

I came across one error message what "no such file or directory" when I run the below command.

```
arm-none-eabi-gcc -g hello.c -o hello -Wl,-Map mapfile.txt
```

> > arm-none-eabi-gcc: error: mapfile.txt: No such file or directory

Would you please help me how can I get the map file What am I supposed to do to resolve this problem?

Comment: You need to supply that `mapfile.txt` to your `arm-none-eabi-gcc` (actually to the `ld` linker)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Did you mean that I need a ld linker file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my fault from http://thehackerworkshop.com/?p=443 ,

> > arm-none-eabi-gcc -g hello.c -o hello -Wl,-Map=hello.map

```
   $(USER_DEFINE) -T $(LINKER_SCRIPT) -o $(BOOTLOADER).o -Wl,-Map=$(BOOTLOADER).map
```

it's work